# How to eliminate deprecation warnings when saving in Glade?

Tags: c, user-interface, gtk3, glade

Each time I save a project in Glade, I get the message
`Project "project.ui" has errors. Save anyway?` I can't seem to find a way to resolve this issue.

I checked the following:

- Glade version is 3.38.2
- The target is set to Gtk 3.24
- Installed Gtk lib is 3.24.34
- As an example, one of the widgets gets complaint: `[MainWindow > GtkBox > GtkGrid > GtkGrid > mainwin_chart_z0_cbtext] Property 'Double Buffered' of object class 'Widget' is deprecated`.
  I didn't change the default property, and even checked the `.ui` file and it doesn't mention `Double Buffered` in that widget's XML.
- Same happens with `Property 'Margin on Left' of object class 'Widget' is deprecated` and several other properties.

So, why do I get the complaint in the first place, and how do I eliminate this?